# Getting error in bash script in azure devops pipeline for power app solutions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, powerapps, tfvc

Getting error while running this pipelines,
this is pipeline for Export solution then unpack the solution and push to TFVC repo in azure devops. please check the following screenshot for your reference

[Pipeline task details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70e6h.png)

[Pipeline picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VreUM.png)

Answer (score 0):

1 Firstly you should know the syntax for using these environment variables depends on the scripting language, for example:

```
PowerShell script: $env:VARIABLE_NAME
Bash script: $VARIABLE_NAME
```

And you can refer the document : [Define Variables](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F74107686%2Fgetting-error-in-bash-script-in-azure-devops-pipeline-for-power-app-solutions&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7C6f3a516b1f8c495e484108dab7f1f454%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638024547067275692%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=GQpBcAbd%2F%2Bm3l3vXhvW0ZnVUL%2FiHlVs6BXyh8rpT8Cw%3D&reserved=0)

2 from your screenshot, you use $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN in your bash script and the running log shows that

```
Both a username and password must be explicitly provided when using/logintype:serviceidentity.
```

As you can see, it indicates the server cannot recognize the variable you provided because your syntax for using is wrong.

3 you can use PowerShell script instead of bash script

[The task PowerShell Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fwfU.png)

then you can run the Power Shell script successfully

Comment: How the issue is going ? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer.  If not, i‘ll stay focused on your issue.